# Error while running npm start for ng2-admin-master, Error: HtmlWebpackPlugin: could not load file dll\vendor.dll.js.map

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2-app using ng2-admin-master dashboard and IDE i used its Visual studio 2015 update 3, i have taken latest code today(March 03, 2017) from ng2-admin github repository [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin), after that i am able to run dependency packages using npm install and finally i ran command npm start, then found below issue.
so could you please tell me the solution to run ng2-admin dashboard in Visual studio 2015 update 3

- Note: I also tried same with Websotrm IDE so i think there no any concern with IDE.
- Below is error,

  Html Webpack Plugin:   Error: HtmlWebpackPlugin: could not load file D:\Workspace\TestApp\ng2-admin-master\dll\vendor.  dll.js.map

  - index.js:313 
    [ng2-admin-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:313:27
  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
  - promise.js:510 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:510:31
  - promise.js:567 Promise._settlePromise
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:567:18
  - promise.js:612 Promise._settlePromise0
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:612:10
  - promise.js:687 Promise._settlePromises
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:687:18
  - async.js:133 Async._drainQueue
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:133:16
  - async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:10
  - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
    [ng2-admin-master]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following command so  that you can pick up the code from the local repository:

```
npm run prebuild:prod && npm run build:prod && npm run server:prod
```

Comment: @arco444 above npm script worked to run the application, but i have one question here that these npm scripts we need to run application on production environment, if i am understood the ng2-admin library, for development environment we use npm start or npm run prebuild:dev && npm run build:dev && npm run server:dev.

Comment: my concerns is there any changes might impacting to run ng2-admin for latest build from github. Somehow i found this issue on [github] (https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues/793) , as this error suggest that vendor.js file could not found in dll folder, so i have created this file and now its works fine with npm start script, so my point is that which is more concern way to fix this problem?

Comment: both of you thanks for your answer this also helpful to run app.